# for singles to meet organically

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does the phrase "for singles to meet organically" mean "for single persons to meet naturally"?

> New York Times tweeted:
> With television shows like “Million Dollar Matchmaker” and “Indian Matchmaking,” and a pandemic that has made it harder **for singles to meet organically**, matchmaking is hot again.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's exactly what it means.

The word "organically" here means in the normal course of living one's life, e.g. to develop a relationship with someone whom you happen to run into every morning when buying a cup of coffee is organic, as opposed to meeting someone because you were setup by some third party for the express purpose of y'all developing a relationship.